# Does a Sparkfun Redboard Arduino Uno have built-in RTC?

Tags: arduino-uno, lcd, rtc

I have a [Sparkfun Redboard](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13975) (an Arduino Uno like board based on the Atmega328P and programmed with the Arduino bootloader).

I have been trying to make an accurate clock without an RTC with an LCD screen and it's been hard.

Does the Sparkfun Redboard have built-in RTC?

Comment: Sparkfun Redboard is NOT Arduino Uno

Comment: the schematic is right on the sparkfun.com website ... have you looked at it?

Comment: @jsotola yes I have p.s. it works like an Arduino uno

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sparkfun Redboard and Arduino Uno do not have built-in RTC.

Answer (score 1):

The new "[Sparkfun Redboard Turbo](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/14812)" does have an RTC on pins A5 and AREF